# Update SQL table using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

i'm having table with columns

```
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CompanyID] [bigint] NULL,
[EmployeeName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[EmployeeGSM] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[EmployeeNumberOfDaysOfAnnualLeaveInEachMonth] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
[EmployeeTotalNumberOfAnnualLeave] [decimal](7, 2) NOT NULL
```

on every month 1st at 00:00:00 i need to update the column EmployeeTotalNumberOfAnnualLeave increment by EmployeeNumberOfDaysOfAnnualLeaveInEachMonth value using trigger

With Regards

Comment: You may be looking for a scheduled job as opposed to a trigger

Comment: Triggers are meant to take action when some other action is performed in a table, not for executing scheduled tasks.

Comment: thank you...if i create a job and scheduled it....if backup my database and restored in other pc do i need to create a new job?

Comment: Yes. Jobs are not a part of database.

Comment: It would almost always be better to store the raw information about e.g. leave taken as discrete rows in an appropriate table and then just calculate these totals when required. When you *store* totals that could be computed from other data, you're immediately opening yourself up to the possibility that the total is incorrectly updated.

Comment: is there is any option other than trigger and job?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the SQL should be `UPDATE Table SET EmployeeTotalNumberOfAnnualLeave = EmployeeTotalNumberOfAnnualLeave + EmployeeNumberOfDaysOfAnnualLeaveInEachMonth`

You could:

1) Create a stored procedure to perform the task:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateEmployeeTotalNumberOfAnnualLeave
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table 
    SET EmployeeTotalNumberOfAnnualLeave = EmployeeTotalNumberOfAnnualLeave + EmployeeNumberOfDaysOfAnnualLeaveInEachMonth
END
```

2) Create a scheduled job:

> 1) Expand Sql Server Agent
>
> 2) Right Click Jobs --> New Job
>
> 3) Give it a name
>
> 4) Go to Steps --> New --> Set it to execute your procedure
>
> 5) Schedules --> New --> Set it to execute on the first of each month
>
> 6) Enable the job